# `background-image` fails to render on `<body>`

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add a background image to the body tag in CSS, but it is not working. I have added the stylesheet which is `main.css`. I don't know where I went wrong ; it might be a silly mistake, but I can't find it. Please help!

```css
.nav-pills {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("\images\1.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">CONTACT ME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">SKILLS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try background-image: url("/images/1.jpg");

Comment: could u share the contents of `main.css` ?

Comment: check your background image path !

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, you are using backslashes instead of forward slashes for your URL. It should read:

```
body {
  background-image: url("/images/1.jpg");
}
```

### Full Code:

```css
.nav-pills {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {                                    /* (Fallback for Demo Purposes) */
  background-image: url("/images/1.jpg"), url(http://placehold.it/100/100/);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">CONTACT ME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">SKILLS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help! I would always appreciate an accept vote if you could spare the time :)

Answer (score 0):

I am Unable to Comment right Now thats Why writing as an Answer,

you are giving Background Image, First Check What is the Image Size and Then try to give the Width and Height in css Like :

```
body{
      background-image: url("\images\1.jpg");
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to check from console-element that is your image is getting proper url or not.

- From there you should verify first
- Instead of "\" use "/" or can use full url

  ```
  body {
    background-image: url("/images/1.jpg");
  }
  ```

OR

```
body {
      background-image: url("www.example.com/images/1.jpg");
    }
```